# SAP Hybris logs to Application Insights are very large(more than 100 GB per day for Production)

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using Application Insights for logging for all the microservices which work fine and data is not that too large.
But when We send our SAP Hybris Commerce logs(6.7 version) it is sending the humongous amount of logs to Application Insight(more than 100 GB) for INFO level which is creating huge costs just for logging. Please provide some ways to reduce the not useful Hybris logs to be sent to Azure Application Insights. Please suggest what can be the best solution for this.

Comment: Consider monitoring less. Why not just log those events outside a given range, which means all events within spec are not recorded.

Comment: These are events which are directly being appended from log4j2 to Application insight Appender and sent to Application Insight. We changed the log level to Error. However, we are still getting 40-50 gb of logs on a daily basis which costs 150 dollars a day. Can you please explain how to not log these log events based on what criteria?

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any reason why you should keep the logging level of `INFO` in production. As you can see the in the [image](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.7.0.0/en-US/8b2c4a4286691014894a812a097cb276.html) below, `Log4j` differentiates five such log levels (in ascending order): `DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, NONE`.

[image]

You should change the logging level of the classes to `ERROR` which will enable only `ERROR` and `FATAL` to be captured. In production, at most it should be `WARN` which will enable only `WARN`, `ERROR` and `FATAL` logs to be captured.

## How to change log level?

There are two ways to do it:

1. Temporary: Login to hAC (Hybris Admin Console) ▸ ⁨Platform ▸ ⁨Logging and search the fully-qualified name of a class (e.g. `de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearch`) and then change its logging level. This change will remain effective until you restart the server. Another way to do it temporarily is by using scripting but it requires knowledge of the `groovy` script.
2. Permanent: Put the configurations into the `local.properties` file. Note that it will require restarting the server to become effective. A sample configuration:

   ```
   log4j.logger.my.package = WARN
   log4j.logger.org.training.service.MyServiceImpl = ERROR
   ```

**Further reading:** https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.7.0.0/en-US/8c07853c866910148a00baf81ea1669e.html

Comment: H Arvind,
Thanks for the reply. The issue is we have set the default level to INFO in local.properties because we need to send info console logs to Splunk. However, when we did the same for App Insight It incurs huge costs. We have changed the logging level for Application Insight Appender to ERROR. but still, we are getting 40-50 GB logs which cost 150 dollars a day just for logging errors. We need some other solution for this problem.